# Vault state's status to UNCONSUMED/CONSUMED

Tags: kotlin, corda

I have taken Bank flow's output as input and updated the value. But I don't know that how to update the vault's state status to "CONSUMED". I thought it will happen automatically based on flowlogic.

Bank Node initiated the flow and committed to both Bank and Customer ledger.
Customer Node initiated another flow and take Bank's state as input, updated the value and committed on both Customer and Bank ledger as new state.
I have done up to this level and below the is sample code.

```
 @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        // Stage1.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
        // Extract state from ledger as input for Customer node
        val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
        val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<POCState>(criteria)
        val pocState = results.states.last().state.data
        // Customer reset the approval status
        val ourOtherOutputStateVB: POCState = pocState.copy(stateCode = pocStateCodeVB, stateCodeMessage = pocStateStringVB)
        // Generate an unsigned transaction.
        val txCommand = Command(BankContract.Commands.Create(), pocState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(StateAndContract(ourOtherOutputStateVB, POC_CONTRACT_ID), txCommand)

        // Stage 2.
       progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
       // Verify that the transaction is valid.
       txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Stage 3.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        // Sign the transaction.
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // Stage 4.
        val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartyFlow), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

        // Stage 5.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
    }
```

Now, my question is:
How to change Bank's state to "Consumed" after Customer node used that as input. So that Customer node can not initiate the flow again for that same Bank state. This will ensure that ALWAYS Bank should initiate the flow and then customer can respond to that flow.

Answer (score 0):

As part of `FinalityFlow`, the transaction will be sent to all the participants of all the states in the transaction (or all of the states' owners, if they are `OwnableState`s). Upon receiving the transaction, each node will verify that it is valid and fully signed, and then record it in its vault. At this point, the node's vault will mark any input states to the transaction as consumed.

If you're finding that after running the flow, one of the input states is not being marked as consumed on the bank node, you should check whether the bank node is receiving the transaction as part of `FinalityFlow`.

Comment: Looks like I have not explained in proper way... 1) Bank node create state and send to Client (i.e., committed in both ledgers using FinalityFlow). 2) Client node copy that (UNCONSUMED) state and modify the values then send back to Bank's and Client's ledger. Total 2 flows here Bank to Client and Client to Bank. Now my issue is: If Client node try to start flow 2nd time it should not be allowed since Client need UNCONSUMED input state from Bank.

Comment: I checked bank node has received the transactions. But I don't see that input state as consumed. Can you let me know how to change vault state's status to consumed manually please?

Comment: The state will be marked as consumed automatically. This isn't something you do manually. As soon as the node sees a transaction that consumes a given state, it will mark the state as consumed.

Comment: @Omganesh Try to check if you see any error in Notary node logs.